# How can i filter DateField with range in react admin

Tags: react-admin

I want to filter dateField with range, for example i have this field:

`<DateField source="starts_at" showTime/>`

starts_at = 2021-10-24 12:16:31.843+03

and i want to filter this field with range, how can i do it?

Comment: Filtering is performed only on the server, the starts_at field will be added to the request and you must process it on the server.

Comment: any luck in that situation?